# Checkins via Swarm App @ Pebble Time will not be shown in herenow

Tags: foursquare, pebble-watch

When using the Swarm app at Pebble Time Smartwatch, the checkins will be recognized within the app but not be shown via API "herenow". Is there any reason for that?